# Replacing an element in an object array

Tags: javascript

I want to replace the entire object in an array.

http://jsfiddle.net/CWSbJ/

```
var array = [ {name: "name1" }, { name: "name2" } ];
var element = array[0];
element = {name: "name3"};
alert(array[0].name);
```

In this piece of code I would expect the output name3, why can't I replace an entire object in an array like this? And what is the good way to do this?

Comment: You are just assigning an other value to `element`, not to `array[0]`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct way is

```
array[0] = {name: "name3"};
```

Your existing code does not work as expected because you are taking a referenc* to the first element with

```
var element = array[0];
```

and then you are *replacing the value of this local variable* with another object. This leaves the original array unmodified.

Comment: I think you should try array[i].name="you value to assign", if you follow array[i]={name:'something'}, every object property gets assign with only name all will be null in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
var array = [ {name: "name1" }, { name: "name2" } ];
array[0] = {name: "name3"};
alert(array[0].name);
```

`element` is not the actual array - its a copy of the array